# HTML dynamic table for displaying search results

Tags: php, forms, search

Am using the following form to fetch and display search items from a database.

```
                <?php
                include('search.class.php');
                $search = new search;
                //table to search
                $search->table = 'xxxxxx';
                //array to show results
               $result = array('Column1', 'column2');
                ?>
              <p> Insert a field to search</p>
              <p> For user between, an not between, use the boollean operator AND </p>
               <p> For search with more words, use the boollean operator OR</p>
               <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
                <?=$search->fieldSelect()?>
                <?=$search->whereSelect()?>
                <?=$search->fieldText(10,20)?>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
                </form>
                 <?=$search->result($result)?>
```

The results are displayed right after the last line.

How can i display them in a neat table?

Comment: you know about html tables ? http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/html-mysql-php

Comment: Thanks. i know about tables but my problem is where to put the code which makes the table. Is it in the search.class.php file or on the part above?